# C# datagridviewbuttoncolumn no text showing

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need to show some texts on the `DataGridViewButtonColumn`. I've read lots of similar question about these on `SO`. Many of them answers recommend setting `UseColumnTextForButtonValue`to `True` which doesn't for me. It seems in an odd way that `Microsoft` makes it to have at least a `row` so that the button will display the text.

The following is my code:

```
        DataGridViewButtonColumn EditColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        EditColumn.HeaderText = "Complete";
        EditColumn.Name = "Complete";
        EditColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True;
        dataGridView.Columns.Add(EditColumn);
```

This code doesn not show the text on the `DataGridViewButtonColumn`:

The code that works here:

```
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "a";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "b";

        ArrayList row = new ArrayList();
        row.Add("1");
        row.Add("2");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());

        DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        btn.Name = "text";
        btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(btn);
```

This code works but however I am getting my data from a database and thus I won't be using `dataGridView.Rows.Add(row.ToArray())` here. So how do I get the text to show on the `DataGridViewButtonColumn` ?

Comment: Check [this Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256811/datagridview-button-text-not-appearing-despite-usecolumntextforbuttontext-set-to)

Comment: See [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/64110c71-aa5c-40b4-a22f-ed800c603392/showing-text-on-the-buttons-in-datagridviewbuttoncolumn-c?forum=winformsdatacontrols) for how to do the binding.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems to solve:

- How **bind** a `Button` column to a `DataSource`
- How to make the `DataSource` create not only default column types but also one (or more) button column

[image]

The first issue is basically solved by setting the `DataPropertyName` of the column.

But I do not know how or even if it is possible to influence the `ColumnTypes` created automatically.

Therefore I suggest a workaround: Instead of relying on the `AutoGenerateColumns` we can do it ourselves in a little helper function:

This clears the columns and creates a new one for each column in a `DataTable`, using the properties of the columns in the table. To tell it which column(s) we want to be buttons we pass a string with the column names, surrounded by spaces:

```
void CreateSpecialColumns(DataTable dt, DataGridView dgv, string buttons)
{
    dgv.Columns.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++ )
    {
        DataColumn dc = dt.Columns[i];
        if (buttons.Contains(" " + dc.ColumnName + " "))
        {
            DataGridViewButtonColumn buttonColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            buttonColumn.HeaderText = dc.Caption;
            buttonColumn.Name = dc.ColumnName;
            buttonColumn.ValueType = dc.DataType;
            buttonColumn.DataPropertyName = dc.ColumnName;
            dgv.Columns.Add(buttonColumn);
        }
        else 
        {   // normal columns
            int c = dgv.Columns.Add(dc.ColumnName, dc.Caption);
            dgv.Columns[c].ValueType = dc.DataType;
            dgv.Columns[c].DataPropertyName = dc.ColumnName;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I called it using a `DataTable DT`:

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
CreateSpecialColumns(DT, dataGridView1, " Cook Waiter ", "");
dataGridView1.DataSource = DT;
```

Note that this only works if the `UseColumnTextForButtonValue` property is **not** set to true!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Text` property,

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn EditColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
EditColumn.HeaderText = "Complete";
EditColumn.Name = "Complete";
EditColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True;
EditColumn.Text = "Complete";                  // --Text property added

dataGridView.Columns.Add(EditColumn);
```