# Create datacolumns from datagridview columns

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview, vb.net-2010

I have a datagridview with columns that I have created at design time.

I now want to create a datatable with the same columns as in the gridview programatically.

I tried the following code.

```
Dim dataTable As New DataTable
For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In dgDocEntries.Columns
   dataTable.Columns.Add(col)
Next
```

This throws a compile error: value of DataGridViewColumn cannot be converted to DataColumn. Obviously I tried casting the types but it didn't work.

I can't use the datasource property to clone/copy either because I am setting the rows manually.

Comment: Do the reverse: create a DT with the desired columns, add data to the datatable then use it as a datasource - the DGV will create columns from that.  You might also be better off using a List<T> datasource if the data doesnt come from or go to a database.

Comment: @Plutonix I can't do it, because sometimes I am setting the datasource from data coming from a database. Sry for not mentioning it initially.

Comment: Look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815757/c-sharp-datagridviewbuttoncolumn-no-text-showing/37819479#37819479) which does the opposite: It creates DGV columns from a DataTable. You should be able to use the same properties to acoomplish the reverse..

Comment: Create the DT from the DB table.  Add or dont add data, doesnt matter.  `dgv.DataSource = myDT` will create the columns in the dgv for you.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines could do the job:

```
void CopyTableColumnsFromDGV(DataGridView dgv, DataTable dt)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvCol in dgv.Columns)
    {
        DataColumn dtCol = new DataColumn(dgvCol.Name, dgvCol.ValueType);
        dtCol.Caption = dgvCol.HeaderText;

        dt.Columns.Add(dtCol);
    }
}
```